# ORA-01810: format code appears twice

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, date-formatting

Why is the sql below generating an ORA-01810 error? I researched the error and I am using different date formats for each date insert

```
INSERT INTO bag_grte_clm
(
    schd_dprt_ldt,
    arr_trpn_stn_cd,
    bkg_crtn_gdt,
    sbmt_bag_grte_clm_dt,
    bag_grte_clm_stt_cd,
    lst_updt_gts,
    bag_grte_clm_gts,
    dprt_trpn_stn_cd
)
VALUES (
    TO_DATE('2015/12/06', 'yyyy/mm/dd'),
    'YUL',
    TO_DATE('2015-11-15', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
    TO_DATE('120615', 'MMDDYY'),
    'DENIAL',
    (current_timestamp),
    TO_TIMESTAMP('20151206 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss'),
    'ATL'
)
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> TO_TIMESTAMP('20151206 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss')

It is wrong in two ways:

**1. Incorrect format code**

You have repeated the `MM` format mask twice. `MM` is **month** and `MI` is **minutes**.

```
SQL> SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP('20151206 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss') FROM dual;
SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP('20151206 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss') FROM dual
                                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01810: format code appears twice
```

**2. Incorrect time portion**

`00:00:00` is wrong as it would throw **ORA-01849** since the *hour cannot be zero, it must be between 1 and 12*.

```
SQL> SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP('20151206 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss') FROM dual;
SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP('20151206 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss') FROM dual
                     *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12
```

The correct way is to either use **24 hour** format, or leave the **time portion** which would default to `12 AM`.

For example,

**24 hour format:**

```
SQL> SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP('20151206 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh24:mi:ss') my_tmstamp FROM dual;

MY_TMSTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
06-DEC-15 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

**No time portion:**

```
SQL> SELECT  TO_TIMESTAMP('20151206', 'yyyymmdd') my_tmstamp FROM dual;

MY_TMSTAMP
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
06-DEC-15 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

Answer (score 21):

You've used the `mm` format code twice in `TO_TIMESTAMP('20151206 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss')`

`MM` is for **month**
`MI` is for **minute**
You probably meant to use `YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS`.

Please see the list of [date format models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm) for more information.

Comment: `TO_TIMESTAMP('20151206 00:00:00', 'yyyymmdd hh:mi:ss')` is still wrong. It will throw **ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12**.